# Sed removing text from a File

Tags: bash, awk, sed, mv

i have a log file with the following lines

"**TSAGE_20160304193254_AAA_29792A_1103.tgz:Binary file (standard input) matches**"

i need to remove the first of the line up to 29792A and the text after that so the file just looks like this:

```
29745gv92A
297342A
2934792A
29755692A
29778892A
```

Comment: Did you try something like `cut -d"-" -f4` ?

Comment: i dont how how to use cut . do i use it with sed?

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide a minimalist example of the input, the expected output, and the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cut to get something between delimiters like an `_`.
When you want to redirect it to another file, use

```
cut -d"_" -f4 logfile > otherfile
```

You can do something like this with `sed`, but you will need to tell sed that it will have to skip the pattern `[^_]*_` (character except underscore repeated 0 or more times) followed by an underscore). You have to skip this (pattern) {3} times from the `^` beginning of the line.
The second string you match `([^_]*)` is the part you want. The `.*` is the rest of the line and is garbage.
The first part of sed will have 2 strings remembered, so recall `\2` to get the second.
Together with backslashes you will have

```
sed 's/^\([^_]*_\)\{3\}\([^_]*\).*/\2/' logfile
```

I did not test the `sed` command, the `cut` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhap this might work:

```
awk -F_ '{print $4}' file
29792A
```